# Salesforce INCLUDES to accept field name

Tags: formula-field

I have a formula field and would like to compare a value from multipicklist to another text field. I am using INCLUDES function to achieve this, but the second argument it expects is a text.

There was some reference to use "&field_name&" or "&text(field_name)&" as second argument, but doesn't seems to be working.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Including your current formula field, as well as the error message **verbatim**, would likely help you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

INCLUDES lets you determine if the multiselect list includes a particular value. It works like this:

```
INCLUDES(MultiselectField, Text)
```

So, you could do something like this:

```
IF(INCLUDES(Field__c,'Value1'),'Value1','') &
IF(INCLUDES(Field__c,'Value2'),'Value2','') &
IF(INCLUDES(Field__c,'Value3'),'Value3','')
```

The second parameter needs to be a text value, which may be a literal text string, another text field, or any other type of field that can be converted via the TEXT function.

Comment: Correct, but there was a comment from one post on Salesforce as below https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gpVdAAI to accept field name.

Comment: is it necessary to hardcode the second text? I am not sure but it should accept values from other fields. 

Comment: I tried just entering the variable name, but its not evaluating the value in the second field. It is considering it as a text.

Comment: @AashishSharma No, you're right. I'm not sure why I said that.

Comment: @Gopi The second field should be a text; INCLUDES returns true if the multiselect list contains a value matching the text, false otherwise.

Comment: @gopi in second parameter of INCLUDES, try putting this : TEXT(FieldToBeMatched)

Comment: @Aashish that didn't work. It will throw an error saying the the field is already of text value.

Comment: @gopi if field to be matched is already text then just put the field name directly in second parameter of INCLUDES, like this : FieldToBeMatched.  dont use any quotes '

Comment: @AashishSharma When I do that, it don't evaluate the value.